# Can I send daily Reminder Emails with a List of Open Cases?

Tags: email, case, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

Is it possible to send out daily reminders to users/contacts a list of open cases? I've looked into some workflows, but they would end up sending multiple emails. I'm looking for a succinct way to remind our users of everything left over from the previous day.

Comment: You could try setting up a report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Schedule a report which will send open cases to your user.

Step 1 :

[image]

Step 2 :

[image]